# Using stream-combiner and Writable Streams (stream-adventure)

Tags: node.js

i'm working on nodeschool.io's stream-adventure. The challenge:

Write a module that returns a readable/writable stream using the
`stream-combiner` module. You can use this code to start with:

```
var combine = require('stream-combiner')
module.exports = function () {
    return combine(
        // read newline-separated json,
        // group books into genres,
        // then gzip the output
    )
}
```

Your stream will be written a newline-separated JSON list of science fiction
genres and books. All the books after a `"type":"genre"` row belong in that
genre until the next `"type":"genre"` comes along in the output.

```
{"type":"genre","name":"cyberpunk"}
{"type":"book","name":"Neuromancer"}
{"type":"book","name":"Snow Crash"}
{"type":"genre","name":"space opera"}
{"type":"book","name":"A Deepness in the Sky"}
{"type":"book","name":"Void"}
```

Your program should generate a newline-separated list of JSON lines of genres,
each with a `"books"` array containing all the books in that genre. The input
above would yield the output:

```
{"name":"cyberpunk","books":["Neuromancer","Snow Crash"]}
{"name":"space opera","books":["A Deepness in the Sky","Void"]}
```

Your stream should take this list of JSON lines and gzip it with
`zlib.createGzip()`.

HINTS

The `stream-combiner` module creates a pipeline from a list of streams,
returning a single stream that exposes the first stream as the writable side and
the last stream as the readable side like the `duplexer` module, but with an
arbitrary number of streams in between. Unlike the `duplexer` module, each
stream is piped to the next. For example:

```
var combine = require('stream-combiner');
var stream = combine(a, b, c, d);
```

will internally do `a.pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d)` but the `stream` returned by
`combine()` has its writable side hooked into `a` and its readable side hooked
into `d`.

As in the previous LINES adventure, the `split` module is very handy here. You
can put a split stream directly into the stream-combiner pipeline.
Note that split can send empty lines too.

If you end up using `split` and `stream-combiner`, make sure to install them
into the directory where your solution file resides by doing:

```
`npm install stream-combiner split`
```

Note: when you test the program, the source stream is automatically inserted into the program, so it's perfectly fine to have `split()` as the first parameter in `combine(split(), etc., etc.)`

I'm trying to solve this challenge without using the 'through' package.

My code:

```
var combiner = require('stream-combiner');
var stream = require('stream')
var split = require('split');
var zlib = require('zlib');

module.exports = function() {
    var ws = new stream.Writable({decodeStrings: false});
    function ResultObj() {
        name: '';
        books: [];
    }
    ws._write = function(chunk, enc, next) {
        if(chunk.length === 0) {
            next();
        }
        chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
        if(chunk.type === 'genre') {
            if(currentResult) {
                this.push(JSON.stringify(currentResult) + '\n');
            }
            var currentResult = new ResultObj();
            currentResult.name = chunk.name;
        } else {
            currentResult.books.push(chunk.name);
        }

        next();

        var wsObj = this;

        ws.end = function(d) {
            wsObj.push(JSON.stringify(currentResult) + '\n');
        }
    }
    return combiner(split(), ws, zlib.createGzip());
}
```

My code does not work and returns 'Cannot pipe. Not readable'. Can someone point out to me where i'm going wrong?

Any other comments on how to improve are welcome too...

Comment: Looks like you need to use duplex stream or have a look at `through` npm package.